# In Lucene.Net, How do I specify a match on any one of a list of terms for a specific field?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

In Lucene.Net, I need to create a query to limit a search to a specific list of terms for a specific field.

For example, I need "AutoMake" to be "Ford" or "Chevy."  So, as long as the value of "AutoMake" is one of those two, we're good.

Here's how I'm forming my BooleanQuery, but I don't think this is right:

```
var query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("AutoMake", "Ford"));
var query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("AutoMake", "Chevy"));

var thisFilter = new BooleanQuery();
thisFilter.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
thisFilter.Add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

The "MUST" there effectively "ANDs" the query, so "AutoMake" has to be *both* "Ford" and "Chevy," which is wrong.  (I've done some reading on the BooleanClause "SHOULD," but I don't think that's right either.)

Essentially, I need a BooleanClause operator for "OR."  I need a way to encapsulate two queries so that if one of them is true, then the entire query is true?  (Because, I have multiple of these queries feeding into a larger query as clauses.)

Here's what would be awesome.

```
var query = new AnyOfTheseTermsQuery();
query.Add(new Term("AutoMake", "Ford"));
query.Add(new Term("AutoMake", "Chevy"));
```

That's what I'm looking for.  Does this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "SHOULD" is the correct operator for this type of query.  It's probably worth your while setting up a small index to test this, but when I look at the documentation, it seems to be exactly what you're after.

Good luck,

Answer (score 1):

Yes add these 2 terms to a BooleanQuery with a SHOULD clause.  That will mean that the query will look for either of those terms.  Then add that query to the parent BooleanQuery with a MUST clause, meaning that the sub query must match a document.